# Flex Panel Content Background Color

Tags: apache-flex, panel, skin

I am trying to set the gradient background color for my panel via skins. I try to change my code but nothing seems to change. Not sure what to do. Thanks for any reply.

My skin file

```
/<!-- layer 2: background fill --/>
        <!--- Defines the appearance of the PanelSkin class's background. -->
        <s:Rect id="background" left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1">
            <s:fill>
                <!--- @private
    Defines the  PanelSkin class's background fill. The default color is 0xFFFFFF. -->
            <s:SolidColor id="backgroundFill" color="red"/>  //Change to red but                 
                                                            //nothing happen....
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
        <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0xFF0000"/>
    </s:fill>
```

Edit:

```
    <s:Rect id="background" left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor id="backgroundFill" color="0xFF0000"/>                
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

I have tried the above code.  It works well.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. Did you really put that code under
/<!-- layer 2: background fill --/> tag inside the skin file and work? As far as I know, I could always use "red", "black" as my color. Change the color to 0x won't change anything. :( +1 for helping me twice though

Comment: I do not put the code under  /<!-- layer 2: background fill --/> tag, it seems it is a comment, but there is one more slash in front of the comment symbol.  I do not try the "red" word.
If they are not typing mistakes in here, I think there many wrong comment indication in your code.

Comment: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2887339#2887339 FYI...The correct answer is here...:P

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The solution is to remove line in overrided updateDisplayList function: backgroundFill.color = getStyle("backgroundColor");

Maybe it could be helpful for other searchers. :)

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was struggling with. There is another finding. This issue wont arise if you "check" the "Remove actionscript styling code" option in the new mxml skin wizard. I guess jerry did the same and he did not get the issue what we both got (other than the typo of the color specification)